# FragmentGridPagerAdapter i and i2 values

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, wear-os

I have a question about the FragmentGridPagerAdapter. When I override the public Fragment getFragment(int i, int i2) function and log the i and i2 values, i get these strange results:

When i swipe right i2 get's increased, so it goes 0, 1, 2 etc. That makes sense.

But let's say I swiped 6 times to the right and then 1 below I would expect i2 to be 6 and i to be 1. However, i2 get's reset to the first position immediately to the first position. Does anyone know what causes this or what's the logic behind this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the getFragment API, this is the actual behavior of the GridViewPager element. It doesn't really behave like a grid - swiping up or down always starts at the first column.

Presumably this was implemented to enforce Google's [design guidelines](https://developer.android.com/design/wear/structure.html#2DPicker) for a 2D picker, which says "Navigation should be vertical-then-horizontal, not horizontal-then-vertical."

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it more readable: the `i` should be named `row` and `i2` should be called `column`.

### But to the point:

The `GridViewPager` is implemented to help you reproduce the Android Wear Home stream behavior. As you know, there are notification cards in the first columns and actions to the right hand side. If you have scrolled to the right to second or third action page for particular notification it would be very confusing to the user if (after swiping up or down) he would land in the middle of action pages for completely different notification. He would see the some action but it would be hard to guess what notification it refers to. So they implement it that way so it resets the current column and returning always to the column with index 0.

This behavior is presented in a video about [Building Advanced UIs for Android Wear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTQ9KKyM9wo#t=2m50s).
About **2:50** this topic is started (the actual explanation is near **3:25** if you want to skip), but I recommend to watch the entire video.

To change this behavior you simply need to override `getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn)` method in your `FragmentGridPagerAdapter` (or just `GridViewAdapter`).

Here is the documentation for that method:

> Returns the column to arrive at when navigating vertically to the
>   specified row.
>
> The default implementation simply returns 0.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ```
> row               the row in question
> currentColumn     the column which is currently centered
> ```
>
> **Returns**
>
> ```
> the column to arrive at
> ```

To achieve what you want you just need to return `currentColumn`, or maybe do some check before returning it to see if this position is valid for the new row.